# $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}|x|$ is a fundamental solution for $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ on $\mathbb R$

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

How to prove that $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}|x|$ is a fundamental solution for $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ on $\mathbb R$.I think it suffice to prove $\hat{(L(F))}=(-4\pi^2x^2)\hat F(x)=1$,where $F$ is a distribution of $\frac{1}{2}|x|$.But I'm stuck in calculating $\hat F(x)$.I guess I should find a function $g$ satisfying $\int \frac{1}{2}|x|\hat \phi(x)dx=\int g(x)\phi(x)dx$ which follows $\hat F=g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{2}|x|\right)=\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{sign}(x)$, so
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(\frac{1}{2}|x|\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{sign}(x)\right)= \delta_0.$$

Comment: All the derivative is in the distribution sense,right?Following your method,I'm trying to calculate the second derivative of $\frac{1}{2}e^{|x|}$.$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{2}e^{|x|}=\frac{1}{2}sign(x)e^{|x|}$,then $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{2}sign(x)e^{|x|}\right)=\delta e^{|x|}+e^{|x|}$,but this seems not following that $\dfrac{1}{2} e^{|x|}$ is a foundamental solution of $\begin{equation}
-\dfrac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} + id
\end{equation}$,do you know where is wrong

Comment: There is a missing coefficient, and $\delta e^{|x|}=\delta$, so $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(\frac{1}{2}e^{|x|}\right)= \delta e^{|x|} + \frac{1}{2}e^{|x|} = \delta +\frac{1}{2}e^{|x|}$, so it's the fundamental solution of that operator (the computation is not rigorous because distributions can not be multiplied, but can justified)

Comment: Why $\delta e^{|x|}=\delta$

Comment: If $f$ is a smooth function, $\delta f = f(0)\delta$. $e^{|x|$ is not smooth, but since the computation is non rigorous you can do it and then prove rigorously the final result